# Porque no me actualiza el css en las paginas php rapido?

Tags: php, css

tengo un problema y no me actuliza los estilos css en la pagina php apenas lo modifico, no se como hacerlo para que me actualice de una vez.

Comment: Truco: Pulsa la tecla SHIFT a la vez que pulsas con el ratón el botón de **refrescar** del navegador que aparece al lado de la barra de la URL y mantenlo apretado hasta que termine de refrescar. Con eso evitas la carga desde la cache y fuerzas la recarga de todos los archivos que generan la página.

Comment: Durante las pruebas y creación de la web, puedes poner un parámetro aleatorio a la carga de archivos .css porque así cada vez que abres la página refrescará ese archivo en lugar de utilizar el de la caché. Ya cuando esté estable, evitas eso. O incluso lo puedes hacer condicionado a una constante general de DEBUG, PRODUCTION o lo que sea. Ejemplo: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilo.css?v=<?php echo mt_rand(); ?>" />`

Answer (score 1):

Recuerda que todo navegador trabaja con cache, en caso de chrome puedes desactivarlo en los ajustes de red al inspeccionar código.

O simplemente puedes recargar la página con ctrl + shift + R, esto recargara la página pero sin tomar en cuenta el cache.